# Should I use a div outside a react element to fetch it by id in jsx and manipulate its style? react-data-grid

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, datagrid, responsiveness

I was working with react-data-grid & had made a custom menu component for a certain column, in that I am not able to fetch the top of the height of the grid, to position my grid  I tried hard coding the values but it lost its responsiveness.

I placed the grid-component inside a div to position it by getting it by Id.

Is it a right approach in the world of react?

Is there a better way to grab the top of the grid??

Comment: kindly share your code snippet

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with how react-data-grid works, but normally in react you'd use a ref if you need to interact with the html element. See here https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html